# Use geoid to match ip to geo locations and visualize that on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-map-user-location-with-geoip-and-elk-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana) tutorial.

Part of my logstash configuration looks like (this all is inside *filter*):

```
 grok {
    match => {
      "message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "%{WORD:verb} %{DATA:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response:int} (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes:int}) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}'
    }
  }

geoip {
      source => "clientip"
      target => "geoip"
      database => "/Users/purajain/Desktop/purak/GeoLiteCity.dat"
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
    }
```

mappings include :

```
"geoip": {
              "dynamic": true,
              "properties": {
                 "location": {
                    "type": "geo_point"
                 }
              },
              "type": "object"
           },
```

Now when I run kibana :

[image]

Here I am not getting geoip information and hence I am not able to create a tile map visualization. It just says no data.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Please ask if I miss out giving any important information.

Comment: The document you're showing has a `grokparsefailure` tag, which means that your grok pattern is probably wrong and thus the geoip filter could not run on `103.47.236.203`.

Comment: @Val Thanks for that observation. The grok pattern I am using is there in the first code snippet and the format of messages can be seen in the last image "message":  .. Can you point out why I am getting `grokparsefailure`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing grok pattern in my logstash configuration file to this solved the problem for me:

```
grok {
 match => {
   "message" => '%{COMMONAPACHELOG} %{QS}%{QS}'
 }
}
```